# Favicon not showing, .htaccess to blame?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I'm having problems getting a favicon to work for my website.

I've got two domains pointing to one hosting account, one points to the root and the other (the one I'm talking about here) to a folder on the root.

They both have .htaccess files to deal with 404 requests, shortening the url and redirecting favicon requests. I'm using .htaccess files because it's relatively easy to do for me (I don't have the time to be changing it to something else).

But this website, the one in a folder on the root, won't show the favicon. Everything is in place as it should be. But it just doesn't show a favicon when I go on to it.

Here's the bit of html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^getfilm.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://getfilm.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.ico    [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://getfilm.co.uk/favicon.ico [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: What happens if you call the favicon directly?

Comment: The above works now for some reason. Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem. You can delete your question if you want using the "delete" link.

Comment: Tried to, won't let me now :/

Answer (score 1):

if you write href="favicon.ico" it means, your icon is located beside your page. if your page is in other folder you need to address the folder/icon.ico

Comment: Yep it's located in the same folder as the page